# i am trying to update the chat using socket io

Tags: reactjs, node.js, socket.io

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
// Importing the Socket from MainChat
import { Socket } from './MainChat';

const Chat = () => {
    // Initializing the socket using the Socket from MainChat
    const socket = Socket;
    const location = useLocation();
    const { userName, room } = location.state;
    const [currentMessage, setCurrentMessage] = useState("");
    const [messageList, setMessageList] = useState([]);
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
    const [displaySearch, setDisplaySearch] = useState([]);
    const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);

    const submit = async () => {
        if (currentMessage !== '') {
            const message = {
                room: room,
                author: userName,
                message: currentMessage,
                time: new Date(Date.now()).getHours() + ":" + new Date(Date.now()).getMinutes(),
            };
            // Emitting the 'send_message' event with the message data
            await socket.emit("send_message", message);
            // Updating the local messageList state
            setMessageList((list) => [...list, message]);
            setDisplay(!display);
            setCurrentMessage("");
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        // Function to save the chat to the database
        const result = async () => {
            const chatName = [room, userName].sort().join('-').toLowerCase();
            await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/chat/addchat", { chatName, chat: messageList });
        };
        // Calling the result function when messageList, room, or userName changes
        result();
    }, [messageList, room, userName]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Function to retrieve the chat from the database
        const result = async () => {
            const chatName = [room, userName].sort().join('-').toLowerCase();
            await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/chat/getsinglechat", { chatName }).then((res) => {
                if (res?.data?.chat?.chat) {
                    // Updating the local messageList state with the retrieved chat
                    setMessageList(res.data.chat.chat);
                }
            });
        };
        // Calling the result function when room or userName changes
        result();
    }, [room, userName]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Function to handle incoming messages
        const messageHandler = (data) => {
            setMessageList((list) => [...list, data]);
        };
        // Listening for the 'receive_message' event and calling the messageHandler
        socket.on("receive_message", messageHandler);
        // Cleaning up the event listener when the component unmounts
        return () => {
            socket.off("receive_message", messageHandler);
        };
    }, [display, socket]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Function to fetch user data for search functionality
        axios.get("http://localhost:8000/user/getUser").then((data) => {
            const result = data.data.user;
            let filteredResult = [];
            if (searchText) {
                // Filtering user data based on the search text
                filteredResult = result.filter((a) => a.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()));
            }
            // Updating the displaySearch state with the filtered result
            setDisplaySearch(filteredResult);
        });
    }, [searchText]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <input
                    className='border border-black mt-5'
                    placeholder='search....'
                    onChange={(e) => setSearchText(e.target.value)}
                />
                <div className='bg-gray-400 w-44 fixed max-h-14 overflow-y-scroll'>
                    {/* Displaying the filtered search results */}
                    {displaySearch.map((a) => {
                        return <div key={a._id}>{a.name}</div>;
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={`border border-black w-80 h-96 overflow-y-scroll`}>
                {/* Displaying the chat messages */}
                {messageList &&
                    messageList.map((mes, i) => {
                        return (
                            <div
                                key={i}
                                className={
                                    mes.author === userName
                                        ? 'bg-red-400 rounded-l-lg w-[60%] mb-3 float-right'
                                        : 'bg-blue-400 rounded-r-lg w-[60%] mb-3 float-left'
                                }>
                                <p>{mes.message}</p>
                                <div className='flex text-xs'>
                                    <p className='pr-3 '>{mes.author}</p>
                                    <p>{mes.time}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
            </div>
            <div>
                <input
                    value={currentMessage}
                    onChange={(e) => setCurrentMessage(e.target.value)}
                    onKeyPress={(e) => e.key === "Enter" && submit()}
                    className='border-2 border-black my-5'
                />
                <button onClick={submit} className='border-2 border-black my-5'>
                    send
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Chat;
```

it is chat application the message is getting updated in the sender side but it is not getting updated in the receiver side .but when I refresh the page in the receiver side the message is displayed but it should be updated in real time.it is chat application the message is getting updated in the sender side but it is not getting updated in the receiver side .but when I refresh the page in the receiver side the message is displayed but it should be updated in real time.